# XCTest Reference to View Controller not Assessable via RootViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, xctest

I have a application with `UIViewController` "hierarchy" of this form:

Tab Bar Controller
- View Controller 1
- View Controller 2
- View Controller 3
  * View Controller 4

I am using the `XCTest` Framework to write test methods for my `iOS` application. View controller 3 is a `UITableViewController`. When the user selects a row in the table, view controller 4 is shown.

I make a call to the application's window to get the root view controller, the tab bar controller for the application:

```
// get reference to the tab bar controller
let tabBarController = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate!.window!!.rootViewController! as! UITabBarController
```

But that only gets me access to the three view controllers corresponding to each tab. I checked the number of child view controllers for the root view controller and the number is 3. Makes sense. I checked the number of child view controllers for the 3rd view controller...zero. The view controllers are all setup via IB. I still need to somehow get access to the 4th view controller for my test. Is there a programmatic way to reach the 4th view controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good night's grinding got me to the answer:

In my test code, I was making a call on the UITableView using this:

selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:

But that method call does not trigger the UITableViewSelectionDidChangeNotification notification to get posted. Since my application's code does use the UITableView delegate function that depends on that notification's posting, I instead just did this:

```
// get reference to the table view
let tableView = tableViewController.view.viewWithTag(300)! as! UITableView
tableView.delegate!.tableView!(tableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
```

Doing the row selection this way triggered my table view's delegate method to be called and thus the

```
performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:
```

inside of that method was called.

The view controller responsible for displaying the site details was loaded and I was able to get a reference to it using the presenting table view controller's method:

```
let detailViewController = tableViewController.presentedViewController!
```

This seems to work and I am satisfied thus far...